# Most efficient way to replace unicode characters from a string in C++ 17

Tags: c++, string, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I need a string of only ASCII characters, I get the original string from a text file, so it could contain any character, and I want to replace those encoded characters with a space or some other char

the reason why I only need ASCII is because I need to identify tokens, keywords, literals, etc, and the reason why I don't need to modify the original string, or throw an error is because what I am doing isn't a compiler, it's a kind of intellisense/autocompletition for a little known language

If that's not the correct approach, and I should iterate over the original string anyway, how can I read encoded characters as just one char?

Comment: What is the encoding of the original Unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16 etc ?

Comment: it could be any encoding, but mostly UTF-8

Comment: Just replace any character whose encoding is >127 with a space. But be careful that `char` maybe a signed type, so you should cast to `unsigned char` before doing this comparison.

Comment: but I want to replace the multichars, 2, 3 or 4, with 1 single whitespace, including the first character, so I keep the same number of columns, wouldn't that add columns?

Comment: @Mis Yes it would but you said you don't know the original encoding, so you have no way of knowing where the multibyte characters are. Of course if you know it's UTF-8 then that's a different story (and a different question).

Comment: So is there a way to know the encoding, and do different things based on that? because keeping the same amount of columns is important in this case

Comment: @Mis No, there is no certain way to know the encoding of a file. There are various ways that you could make a good guess among common file encodings but nothing that is foolproof.

Comment: Then how do text editors know? Anyway, something approximate works for me, most of the time it will be UTF-8, it's the default in any editor, or at least in vscode, where this will extension run

Comment: Text editors know because they make a guess. The same sequence of bytes can be a legal but different strings in two different encodings so it's in principle impossible to know for sure. But if you guess then you'll just need to decode the bytes according to the encoding you have picked and replace the non ASCII characters. That's obvious to say but not so easy to do. Seems like you are looking for some quick answer but there isn't one, except maybe to use a third party library where the work has already been done for you.

Comment: If I was doing this and I was only worried about UTF-8 then I just look up the details of the encoding on wikipedia and write the code. But if I had to cope with 10 different encodings, most of which I'd never heard of before, then I'd probably look to a third party library. It's a judgment call you have to make.

Comment: The fool proof way to encode a text string or file so you and others know it's encoding is to use a BOM (Byte order mark) at the start of the file / string see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: If you are dealing with a small language, you should have definite script, right? You use ASCII, so I assume you want just Latin script? Or really any characters? But so you are asking about Unicode General Category? (spaces, letter [upper, lower, others], symbols, combining marks, etc.)? Maybe if you write a small example text and possible result, we may understand better

Comment: an example: i want to convert `aáeéiíoóuú` to `a e i o u`, replacing characters that occupy 2 bytes, with a single 1 byte space, not 2 spaces. and i mean really any character, I don't want a comment with weird characters to break everything